# Cloud Formation EBS mount issue

Tags: amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to mount a number of volumes during ec2 creation. CF does not complain about the yaml, the stack completes without error, the instances are created, the devices are shown via "lsblk", but no mounting occurs. Below is the stripped down yaml:

For this exercise, I'm only attempting to mount one before I proceed with writing the yaml for the rest.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: "adding instances"
Resources:
Instance01:
Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
Properties:
SubnetId: subnet-xxxxxx
KeyName: 'awesome'
ImageId: ami-xxxxxxx
InstanceType: m5.2xlarge
SecurityGroupIds:
- sg-xxxxxx
- sg-xxxxxx
- sg-xxxxxx
IamInstanceProfile: 'MyRole'
Tags:
- Key: Name
Value: 'awesometag'
BlockDeviceMappings:
- DeviceName: '/dev/xvdb'
Ebs:
VolumeSize: 50
VolumeType: gp2
- DeviceName: '/dev/xvdc'
Ebs:
VolumeSize: 80
VolumeType: gp2
- DeviceName: '/dev/xvdd'
Ebs:
VolumeSize: 50
VolumeType: gp2
- DeviceName: '/dev/xvde'
Ebs:
VolumeSize: 50
VolumeType: gp2
- DeviceName: '/dev/xvdf'
Ebs:
VolumeSize: 50
VolumeType: gp2
- DeviceName: '/dev/xvdg'
Ebs:
VolumeSize: 50
VolumeType: gp2
UserData:
Fn::Base64:
!Sub |
#!/bin/bash -xe
mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdc
sleep 5
mkdir -p /mypartition
mount /dev/xvdc /mypartition 
echo "/dev/xvdc /mypartition ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
mount -a
```

(clearly the yaml spacing isn't correct, but that's a copy/paste issue : )

Like I said; the instance is created, but df -h does not show /mypartition and /etc/fstab does not have the entry.

Thank you!

Comment: what does the output of your user data script show?

Comment: Did you create the directory "/mypartition"?

Answer (score 0):

The `mount /dev/xvdc /mypartition` may have caused an error, preventing the script from running further. Try removing it since you already have `mount -a` at the end

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input!  Turns out it was a the ami I was using.